# Sql Server Database project error for return type of user defined function

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, return-type, build-error

I've was trying to create a user defined function in the Sql Server Database project in visual studio 2017, but I encountered a strange error during build time.  This error was generated by the auto sql code builder:

```
RETURNS /* Error: Unsupported type. */
```

Which was accompanied by this message:

"SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'AS'.  Expecting DOUBLE, ID, NATIONAL, QUOTED_ID, TABLE, or VARIABLE."

Has anyone else encountered this issue before?  I've looked in many forums and help sites, and this issue seems to have occurred to many, but I couldn't find any fixes regarding user return types, specifically DataTables.

Does anyone know why this occurs or how to fix it?

Here is my code that generated the error:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    public static DataTable getDailyEmpHrs(String strGroupName)
    {
        DataSet dsEmp = new DataSet("myEmpHrs");

        dsEmp.Tables["myEmpHrs"].Columns.Add("ccnumber", typeof(int));
        dsEmp.Tables["myEmpHrs"].Columns.Add("ccname", typeof(string));
        dsEmp.Tables["myEmpHrs"].Columns.Add("cccode", typeof(string));

        DataTable dsTable = dsEmp.Tables["myEmpHrs"];

        return dsTable;
    }
};
```

And Visual Studio generates this code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--    This code was generated by a tool.
--
--    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
--    the code is regenerated.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getDailyEmpHrs] (@strGroupName [nvarchar](MAX))
RETURNS /* Error: Unsupported type. */
AS EXTERNAL NAME [project].[UserDefinedFunctions].[getDailyEmpHrs];

Go

// Generated Assembly Stuff below here
```

Comment: Use a table-valued function instead of scalar function to return an IEnumrable type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243637/returning-table-with-clr.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a scalar (single value) UDF but the c# returns a table.
There is no data type.

It would be `RETURNS TABLE` if anything

But honestly, why have a UDF for this? What advantages do you think you will have?

Comment: This will be one of many UDFs in part for a library that is needed for another program.  Thanks for the reply :)